# How to print the query result into the console | Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the following code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Testing Connect to SQL Server
       ${queryTest}   Execute Sql String     SELECT * FROM users where Id='1'
       #log to console   ${queryTest}   //This print NONE
       #${query_results}   SeleniumLibrary.Get Text  ${queryTest}
       #log to console   ${query_results} 
       #${value}=    Set Variable    ${queryTest[0][0]}
       log to console   ${value} 
       log to console   should display result 
       ${rowCount}=     Row Count   SELECT * FROM users where Id='1'
       log to console   ${rowCount}  
       #rowCount print 1
```

What I'm trying to do is printing the query's result in the console

Comment: What's the outcome of your script? What does it print into console? What errors do you get if any?

Comment: log to console   ${queryTest}   //This print NONE,,
${output} =    Set Variable    ${queryTest[1]}
log to console   ${output} >> This print the following error:
Resolving variable '${queryTest[1]}' failed: IndexError: list index out of range,,, and in the report file it shows "@{queryTest} = [ ]"

Comment: Is your DB connection created successfully? I don't see any `Connect To Database` keyword in the script, it might be elsewhere, but it might be wrong, unsuccessful etc.

Comment: the connection is created successfully as I've printed row count as you see in the code
${rowCount}=  Row Count SELECT * FROM users
       log to console   ${rowCount}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `Execute Sql String` doesn't return anything. There's no [return statement](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/blob/ea0b3d44e6ad59f8c39f901eeed746893d6c7c1f/src/DatabaseLibrary/query.py#L293) in the method, and documentation doesn't mention such an example either (even though they mention a select statement with this keyword, which might be what leads people to believe they eventually get some rows back).

Try using [`Query`](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.2.2/DatabaseLibrary.html#Query) keyword:

```
@{queryTest}    Query    SELECT * FROM users where Id='1'
```